# Where is /bin/bash being changed to /bin/sh?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, gnu-make

I'm catching the following error from my `GNUmakefile`, and I'm trying to understand why `/bin/sh` is being used:

```
$ make diff
/bin/sh: 541: Bad file descriptor
rm -f cryptopp563.diff
```

The recipe is:

```
.PHONY: diff
diff:
    -rm -f cryptopp$(LIB_VER).diff
    $(shell svn diff -r 541> cryptopp$(LIB_VER).diff)
```

I understand where the 541 is coming from. But I don't understand why my shell is being changed from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh`.

```
$ printenv | grep -i shell
SHELL=/bin/bash
$ cat GNUmakefile | grep SHELL
SHELL ?= /bin/bash
```

Where or why is the shell being changed?

Comment: use `make -p | grep -i SHELL`, and you'll find it's `/bin/sh` because that's the default value that's assigned when there's no makefile. Because your makefile has `?=` for the assignment, it doesn't take the new value.

Comment: @Petesh - if there's no makefile, then what is make executing :)

Comment: make has a built-in database of things that get defined - if you run `make -p -f /dev/null` it shows what is defined in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?=` operator only sets the variable if it has no value. If you need bash always, use `=` or `:=` instead.

Make's `SHELL` is not the same as your shell's `SHELL`.

It's documented in *Recipes > Execution > Choosing the Shell*:

> Unlike most variables, the variable `SHELL` is never set from the
>   environment.  This is because the `SHELL` environment variable is used
>   to specify your personal choice of shell program for interactive use.
>   It would be very bad for personal choices like this to affect the
>   functioning of makefiles.  See *Variables from the Environment*.

Comment: But I export `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the environment. Does GNUmake not honor `SHELL`?

Comment: The environment variable SHELL is different from the make's SHELL. Make sets it to `/bin/sh` by default.

Comment: So it sounds like GNU make is doing that thing the free software folks despise: its not honoring my choice :) Since I export `SHELL`, it sounds like its disregarding my selection of shells and doing a `SHELL := <GNU's preference>`. Is that correct? (If so I can accept the answer).

Comment: @jww if you pass in `-e` it allows the environment variable to override the values, you can also pass in `make SHELL=$SHELL`